# My Local Html Ref is not working for some reason

Tags: html

The local referencing does not work for some reason and I have tried countless things. I am using `atom.io` **IDE**, can anybody give a proper solution to this please?

```html
 <h1>
CAS DESIGN TECH CLASS  </h1>
  </body>
</html>

<div id="main_container">
  <p class= "main_title">Contents</p>
<ul class= "main_list">
    <li><a href=  "/Users/Mac/.atom/Makey" >1 Makey Makey</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/Users/Mac/.atom/Makey">2 LittleBits</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#Third_Point_Header_">3 Lego Mindstorms</a>
    </li>
```

Comment: Paste your code that you have so far.

Comment: Ok check now its done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you are facing is due to the reason that you have used absolute path name and it doesn't even contains the complete value in the path like "C:\Users\ganeshkumar\website\about.html"

While working in local system, you can try avoiding absolute pathname and use relative pathname. This will help you to overcome the issue.

You can learn more about the path approach in https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp